# Creating global variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've been working on a small "library" that I would use for Http requests. It's written in TypeScript and it has one primary class which is `Http`. I'd like to be able to use this class in my ordinary JavaScript after including my compiled bundle, so I'm thinking about the way to make it globally available.

I'm using `gulp-tsify` as a compiler and it does compile my TypeScript into the es5 bundle, which is great, but in a different scope as a  self-invoking function. When I rewrite my bundle after it's compiled (code below) it works fine, but how to achieve that without rewriting the bundle script?

What I mean is... my compiled TypeScript looks like this:

```
(function e(t,n,r){ ... })(function(require, module, exports){
    ...
    // Somewhere here I've got var Http_1 = require('/...');
}, n, r)
// console.log(Http_1) -> undefined
```

when I declare the global http like that (manually)...

```
var http;
(function e(t,n,r){
    ...
})(function(require, module, exports){
    ...
    // Somewhere here I've got var Http_1 = require('/...')
    http = Http_1;
    // or I can do this without the Http_1
    http = require('./classes/Http');
}, n, r)
// console.log(http) -> everything's fine
```

... the user is able to use the http object, but I want it to be automatically done by the compiler.

I was thinking about something like `declare var http = Http;` inside TypeScript, but I'm unable to achieve that because the `Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.` Any thoughts on how it could be done? Thank you.

Comment: You should write all of your code in TypeScript using modules.

Comment: Did  you try `window['Http'] = Http;` ?

Comment: @Martin Thank you it works, if you consider writing the answer I'll mark it as correct... just in case anyone else has similar problem.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you, I will definitely take a look on that.

Comment: Ok. I have added this as an answer.

Comment: @SLaks I was reading the question once again after while and I'm wondering how would I benefit in this particular case if the code I write is one big module? Would it then compile to global scope or something? Also if you have some interesting reading for this topic it would be great. It seems to me like a big problem in a larger project to chunk my code into the modules. Thanks

Comment: By "this particular case" I mean... I wanted my code here to be complied and automatically included to a global scope. That's because I want the end-user to just include my bundle to the page (locally or using some cdn - whatever) and use the Http object right away in his es5 scripts on the page.

Comment: @DawidZbiński: I mean you shouldn't do that in the first place.

Comment: @SLaks Well I know it's probably not the best practice, but I just wanted to create a library for the http calls for one of my friends. As he doesn't know the TypeScript and other JavaScript's versions than es5 I thought it'd be a nice way to help. So I hope you understand I couldn't tell him to install a compiler and teach him all the stuff. The other thing is that it would be accessible for more people then if it is a global scoped library - at the end it has only a few kilobytes (30-40). But yeah I understand your point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a browser global simply attach the item to the window object.

```
window['Http'] = Http;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the special global syntax:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        you: IAreCookingWithFire;
    }

    var you: IAreCookingWithFire;
}
```